# How Publish a Cloudnary video with React?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, fetch-api, cloudinary

I am trying to make my website allow the user to upload a video clip to publish it in his post, but I was not able to do that until I created the schema specifically for the video and created a toute and controller function for the video, but I did not know how to build the codes in React that would make the user able to Embed the video in the post that he publishes. All I did was upload the videos through Postman, the video is uploaded to Cloudinary, and the link is stored in the MongoDB database collection.

In short, what I want is for the user to optionally be able to upload the video and have it published in the post in the correct manner. Currently, I can upload photos easily and without problems. I tried to do the same method for the video, but uploading the video must be a different matter because I did not succeed in that.

controller function that I did when uploading the video to Cloudinary in the postman:

```
const uploadVideo = async (req, res) => {
       try {
           cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, 
           {
            resource_type: "video",
            folder: "video",
          },
          async (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
             console.log(err)
             return res.status(500).json("error in upload video 
        function!"+err)
          }
          const upload = new Upload({
            name: req.file.originalname,
            url: result.url,
            cloudinary_id: result.public_id
          });
          await upload.save();
          res.status(200).json(upload)
       })
       } catch (error) {
           console.log(error)
       }
      
       }
```

controller function that creates the post after I modified it so that I can include the video within the post after I successfully included the img:

```
    const createPost = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const {postedBy, text} = req.body;
        let {img} = req.body;
        let {video} = req.body;

        if(!postedBy || !text) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "PostedBy and text fields are required!" })
        }

        const user = await User.findById(postedBy);
        if(!user) {
            return es.status(404).json({ error: "User not found!" })
        }

        if(user._id.toString() !== req.user._id.toString()){
            return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized to create post" })
        }

        const maxLength = 500;
        if(text.length > maxLength){
            return res.status(400).json({ error: `Text must be less than ${maxLength} characters!` })
        }

        if(img){
            const uploadedResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(img);
            img = uploadedResponse.secure_url;
        }

        if(video){ // <= this if statment that i added
            try {
                cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, 
                {
                    resource_type: "video",
                    folder: "video",
                },
                async (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error in video if statment! " + err)
                    return res.status(500).json("error in upload video function!"+err)
                }
                const upload = new Upload({
                    name: req.file.originalname,
                    url: result.url,
                    cloudinary_id: result.public_id
                });
                await upload.save();
                // res.status(200).json(upload)
            })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error in video catch " + error)
            }
        }

        const newPost = new Post({ postedBy, text, img, video })

        await newPost.save();
        res.status(201).json( newPost )

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
        console.log(err)
    }
};
```

the rendering function in react component:

```
const handleCreatePost = async() => {
 setLoading(true)
  try {
 const res = await fetch("/api/posts/create", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({postedBy: user._id, text: postText, img: 
imgUrl, video: videoUrl}) // <= i added "video: videoUrl" to make it accept the video in newPost but it did't work
  })
  
   const data = await res.json();
   if(data.error) {
    console.log("2"+data.error)
    showToast("Error", data.error, "error")
    return;
   }
   showToast("Success", "Post created successfully", "success");
   if(username === user.username) {
   setPosts([data, ...posts]);
   }
   onClose();
   setPostText("");
   setImgUrl("");
 } catch (error) {
   console.log("3"+error)
   showToast("Error", error, "error");
 } finally {
   setLoading(false);
 }
};
```

If there's a way to embed the video without making it a separate schema object, please let me know
Or if I can fetching two api's into one function in React using .then()

Comment: What do you mean by "because I did not succeed in that."? Do you receive some error from the SDK or API, or the video uploads successfully but your application code isn't saving the details to your database correctly afterward?

Comment: @lgy the video is not showing in the post just the post text is shown

Comment: Since video upload might take more time and could be asynchronous, consider handling it separately from the rest of the post creation process.

Also, did you inspect your server logs to see if there are any error messages during the video upload?